# Parse - How to set multiple parent objects

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, parse-platform

For my app, I want an uploaded image to have 2 parent objects because, in my own understanding that's one of the best way to approach it--but please correct me if I'm wrong. Below is the code that I am trying.

```
// Create a PFObject around a PFFile and associate it with the current user
PFObject *userPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
[userPhoto setObject:imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];

PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[userPhoto setObject:user forKey:@"user"];

// Create PFObject and associate userPhoto with Listings as well
PFObject *listings = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Listings"];
userPhoto[@"parent"] = listings;

[userPhoto saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [self refresh:nil];
    }
    else{
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any insights would be helpful

Comment: Make sure the UserPhoto object has the correct type specified for the @"user", and @"imageFile" and @"listing" columns. Either Pointer or Relation.

Comment: I believe in your example a pointer would work

Comment: My problem is with the listings objects. I have a class called "Listings" where all listings are stored, I want an image to be associated with a listing and a user namely currentUser

Comment: Your not assigning a property to the listing. You are making the listing a property of userPhoto. In the code you never add a property to the Listings object.

Comment: What properties or columns are on the Listings object?

Comment: title, description, price, dateCreated, createdByUser are the main columns